# .Net simple regex quadratic complexity

Tags: c#, .net, regex, time-complexity, backtracking

While building a simple **regex** I've found it to have a quite strange **performance** profile while input size increased.

Here is another really basic regex that has a similar behavior:

```
a+b
```

I've profiled it with a simple benchmark:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("a+b", RegexOptions.Compiled);

const int maxInputSize = 100;
const int n = 1000;

string input = "";
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
for (int inputSize = 1; inputSize <= maxInputSize; ++inputSize)
{
    input += 'a';

    stopwatch.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        regex.Match(input);
    }
    stopwatch.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed.Ticks);
}
```

It runs the regex on the strings "a", "aa", "aaa", ... and measure the time it took for each length of the string to do n matches.

I'm aware of the **backtracking** issue (e.g. if the regex was something like `(a+a+)+b`), but in this case even considering backtracking I expected a **linear complexity**.

As an example if we want to match n times 'a' here is the workflow I naively expected:

```
take first 'a'
take second 'a'
...
take last 'a'
ooops nothing more to take => backtracking
release one 'a' and try to match 'b', nothing => backtracking
...
release second 'a' and retry to match 'b', nothing => backtracking
release first 'a'
ooops we're back at the beginning => no match
```

So it should execute something like **2n** operations.

(This documentation seems to confirm that complexity should be linear: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsy130b4.aspx)

But instead I observe a **quadratic complexity**:

[image]

So my questions are:

- 1) were my expectations about linear complexity unreasonable?
- 2) if yes, what am I missing about regex matching?
- 3) if no, is my benchmark flawed? why?
- 4) if my expectations and the benchmark are correct what could be the issue(s)?

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: You may want to increase your sample size where the timings are in seconds, not 100's of ticks as your time provider may not be as accurate as you are expecting.

Comment: @DarrenKopp: good remark but in this case the sample size is consistent with the experiment: it takes tenth of ms, and even with bigger sample size I get the same behavior. Thanks.

Comment: Actually in this link you pointed out there are a lot of suggestions also how to optimize the regular expression and avoid backtracking etc. 
I think in some cases a more sophisticated syntax is needed 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/backtracking-in-regular-expressions?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Regex.Match` function searches for a substring match: the engine tries to match the expression starting at any index of the string, giving an O(n²) algorithm. You can probably achieve linear performance by anchoring the regex to the start of the string:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^a+b$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Comment: Of course >_< ! With this one I have a linear complexity and it's obvious why mine's complexity was quadratic: sliding the window over the string is the missing dimension. Thanks for the quick answer. :)